# Swapping rows and columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a quick way to turn the list in the Column to be in the Row? See example below. Note how the row and column are switched.

[image]

Comment: You're most likely going to want a Pivot Table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a one-off change rather than TRANSPOSE worksheet function you can use the Transpose option while copying and pasting

Copy the original table then choose destination for new table and right click > choose "Paste Special" > Transpose > OK > ESC

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [`TRANPOSE`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/transpose-HP005209319.aspx) function that does exactly that.